# javascript regex match on array to find multiple items

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

Is possible to do a regex match on an array to find all the items containing certain letters?

My array is:

```
var myArray = [
    "move",
    "mind",
    "mouse",
    "mountain",
    "melon"
];
```

I need to find all items containing the letters: **"mo"**, using a regex match like this:

```
/mo\w+/igm
```

To output these words: **'move', 'mouse', 'mountain'**...

I've tried this, but does not work properly, it outputs only one item..

```
Array.prototype.MatchInArray = function(value){
    var i;
    for (i=0; i < this.length; i++){
        if (this[i].match(value)){
            return this[i];
        }
    }
    return false;
};
console.log(myArray.MatchInArray(/mo/g));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't even need RegEx for this, you can simply use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), like this

```
console.log(myArray.filter(function(currentItem) {
    return currentItem.toLowerCase().indexOf("mo") !== -1;
}));
# [ 'move', 'mouse', 'mountain' ]
```

JavaScript Strings have a method called [`String.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), which will look for the string passed as a parameter and if it is not found, it will return -1, otherwise the index of the first match.

**Edit:** You can rewrite your prototype function, with `Array.prototype.filter`, like this

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "MatchInArray", {
    enumerable: false,
    value: function(value) {
        return this.filter(function(currentItem) {
            return currentItem.match(value);
        });
    }
});
```

so that you will get all the matches. This works because, if the regex doesn't match the current string, then it will return `null`, which is considered as falsy in JavaScript, so that string will be filtered out.

**Note:** Technically, your `MatchInArray` function does the same job as `Array.prototype.filter` function. So, better make use of the built-in `filter` itself.

Comment: It still outputs the stuff, but if I put it into a div innerHTML, it seems to work with no problems :) I'm going to use a text input to pass a variable into the regex, do you think that it will work properly?